# Comparison operators for directory_entry are missing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::directory_entry d("test.txt");
    boost::filesystem::directory_entry e("test.txt");

    if (d == e) { // <---- error C2784
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile (Visual Studio 2005, Windows XP SP3) with 17 variations of this error:

```
error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,
                                    const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : 
              could not deduce template argument for 
              'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 
              'boost::filesystem::directory_entry'
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_entry) (I am still using Boost 1.45), there are comparison operators defined for `directory_entry`, but neither me nor the compiler can find them (I checked the headers manually). Am I overlooking something? Could it be that I made a mistake when building boost, maybe by setting some option that disables these operators? Is the documentation wrong? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently this is only supported in the new Version of the library. Defining `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION` as 3 at the start of the program fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you were unable to locate the operator in the header file, then maybe you have a different version of the library? In Boost 1.45, the operator is located in [operations.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp).

Comment: I didn't test it, I have an older version of the library that doesn't have those operators